# How to JOIN data from query with list of data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Two tables with some data in the second one.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dst (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  content varchar(200) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO src VALUES('100', 'ET'), ('200', 'Luke'), ('300', 'Jojo');
```

Now, I insert one selected id from src and some other list of values. So the result should look like this:

```
200, one
200, two
200, three
```

And this is my try of

```
INSERT INTO dst (id, content) 
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT id FROM src WHERE name = 'Luke') AS bar 
CROSS JOIN ('one', 'two', 'three')) AS foo;
```

The issue is how can I put the second argument for JOIN - ('one', 'two', 'three'), because this way doesn't work. `ERROR: syntax error at or near "'one'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` (in your case you didn't alias the column of the second subquery. e.g. `as content`, and comma seperated strings `('one','two','three')` will not work, should be converted to a query )

```
INSERT INTO dst (id, content) 
 SELECT bar.id, foo.content 
   FROM
   (
    ( SELECT id FROM src WHERE name = 'Luke' ) as bar
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
     SELECT 'one' as content UNION ALL
     SELECT 'two' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'three'
    ) as foo
   )
```

Comment: Thank you! It's not very pretty `SELECT 'two' UNION ALL` but I guess that the only way.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use `unnest()` - this will convert an array into rows:

```
select
    unnest(array['one', 'two', 'three']::varchar[]) as content
```

Would yield

```
content (varchar)
---------------
one
two
three
```

This is implicitly cross joined when used in a select statement:

```
insert into dst (
    id,
    content
) (
    select
        src.id,
        unnest(array['one', 'two', 'three']::varchar[])
    from
        src
    where
        src.name = 'Luke'
);
```